# Difference between && and ? for an object

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if there is are a real difference between using `?` and `&&` in typescript.

Example:

```
interface InnerData {
  name: string
  title: string
}

interface OuterData {
  someInnerData: undefined | InnerData
}

const myData: OuterData = {
  someInnerData: {
    name: 'This is a name',
    title: 'This is a title'
  }
}

const bookTitleOneWay = myData.someInnerData?.title

const bookTitleAnotherWay = myData.someInnerData && myData.someInnerData.title

console.log('bookTitleOneWay', bookTitleOneWay)
console.log('bookTitleAnotherWay', bookTitleAnotherWay)
```

In `bookTitleOneWay` I use the `?` operator while in `bookTitleAnotherWay` I use the `&&` operator.
The both produce the same outcome but I would like to know if:

1. Is there a real difference between the two operators? (Except the syntax)
2. Is there a standard that we should use?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question including your point on the syntax.

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment - I misunderstood this to be a ternary vs `&&` question, which it obviously is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a real difference between the two operators?

Yes. `&&` tests its left-hand operand to see if it's *truthy*, which is any value other than `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `false`, `null`, or `undefined`. In contrast, optional chaining (`?` in the context where you've used it) only checks the left-hand operand for `null` and `undefined`.

In your specific example it may not result in any difference because `someInnerData` is typed as `undefined | InnerData` and `InnerData` is defined as an object, but the operators do different things.

> Is there a standard that we should use?

Use the correct one for the data you're testing. If you want a truthiness check, use `&&`. If you want a `null`/`undefined` check, use optional chaining.